# Hover slide tab mechanism

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am currently working with sliding tabs. I am implementing the hover function to trigger the tab to slide to the left. The only thing is that the tab does slide when the mouse hovers it but it closes right away. I would like for the tab to stay open once the mouse hovers it and the only way to close the tab is to click on the initial "arrow" div. Here is a demo of my work: http://jsfiddle.net/eMsQr/6/

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#arrow").hover(
    function(){
      $("#inner").stop().animate({marginRight: "0px", opacity: "1px", height: "100px"}, 500 );
    },
    function(){
      $("#inner").stop().animate({marginRight: "-100px", opacity: "1px", height: "100px"}, 500 );
    }
  );
});
</script>

<html>
<div style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); height: 300px; width: 300px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
    <div id="inner" style="height: 100px; width: 150px; background-color: rgb(0, 204, 102); float: right; margin-right:-150px;" >Form is here</div>

    <div id="arrow" style="height: 100px; width: 50px; background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); float: right; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;" >Arrow is here</div>
</div>​
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eMsQr/13/ does this help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean this? Use [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)- and [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)-event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#arrow")
    .mouseenter(function(){
      $("#inner").stop().animate({marginRight: "0px", opacity: "1px", height: "100px"}, 500 );
    })
    .click(function(){
      $("#inner").stop().animate({marginRight: "-100px", opacity: "1px", height: "100px"}, 500 );
    });
});
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/eMsQr/12/).

Comment: Thank you, .mouseenter was the main key that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#arrow").hover(function(){
      $("#inner").stop().animate({marginRight: "0px", opacity: "1px", height: "100px"}, 500 );
    },
    function(){});
});


$("#arrow").click(function(e){
    $("#inner").stop().animate({marginRight: "-100px", opacity: "1px", height: "100px"}, 500 );
});
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eMsQr/14/).